# Galaxies fading away after time

Tags: visible-light, dark-energy

Dark energy is constantly pulling all objects away from each other with increasing speed. This in turn causes a red-shift of the light from the most distant object where this effect is most profound. This red-shift will gradually increase as the objects move away faster. Is there going to be a time where the objects travelling away will emit light of such long wavelength that they will disappear from sight?

Comment: Yes. Note that this is a technical limitation - if we could detect light of arbitrary wavelengths and intensity, we'd still be able to see them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do galaxies "dissappear?"](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100911/)

Answer (score 1):

In an acceleratingly expanding universe, there will be an emission time of light from a distant galaxy after which we can never recieve newly emitted light.

Old light will eternally be received, but even more dimmer and red shifted.

See [The Long–Term Future of Extragalactic Astronomy](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0107568) for more information.